# Rails: The correct way of returning json from get request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

For example 
when send request

```
GET --> http:://{url}?search={username}
```

I need return:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'sande', nickname: 'username'},
  {id: 2, name: 'sande2', nickname: 'username'}
]
```

This is what I do it:

routes:

```
  resources :users do 
    collection do 
      get :search
    end
  end
```

UsersController

```
  def search
    @users = User.search(params[:query]) if params[:query]
    render json: @users.to_json(:only => [:id, :name, :username])
  end
```

User Model

```
  def self.search(query)
    where(" username ILIKE ? or name ILIKE ? ", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  end
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
def search
  @users = User.where(1)
  @users = @user.search(params[:query]) if params[:query].presence?
  render json: @users.collect{|u| {id: u.id, name: u.name, username: u.username} }
end
```

The first line gets the list of all users from the database.

The second line add search criteria scope if param query is not blank

The third line can be decomposed in 2 parts:

- `@users.collect{|u| {id: u.id, name: u.name, username: u.username} }` creates an `Array` of `Hash` with only the id, name, and username fields
- `render json: ...` tells rails to render the resulting `Array` after automatically make it a json object, so you don't have to call `to_json` manually

Comment: Seems like it returns the whole `user obejct`, how can I customize the return? Just to give `id`, `name`, and `username`.

Comment: And is there any sample code that I can look into? I'm afrain my code is too simple.

Comment: and what about handling empty query? If I run `http://localhost:3000/users/search?query=`. It will return all users. I now use `if !params[:query].blank?` to ensure it, but this does not quite elegant.

Comment: I based my answer on your question, but if you also need to handle empty params I updated my answer

Comment: Don't forget that "thank you" is free and pleases the guy that just answer you annoying questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep `params` will contain the query values on a get request:

```
params[:search]
```

will return your search query.